# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dir'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to start a timer to do some file arvchival job. the code is like this:

```
from threading import Timer

message_archive_dir = "achivedir"
message_archive_format = "zip"
archive_timer = Timer(86400, messageachiver.archive, dir = message_archive_dir, fmt = message_archive_format)
archive_timer.start()


class messageachiver(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.message_archive_dir = dir
            self.message_archive_format = fmt

    def archive(self):
            print("message_archive_dir is " + self.message_archive_dir)
            print("message_archive_format is " + self.message_archive_format)
            print("Archiving trade messages")
```

I got below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sa_listener.py", line 43, in <module>
    archive_timer = Timer(archive_interval, messageachiver.archive, dir = message_archive_dir, fmt = message_archive_format)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dir'
```

I'm not sure why _*init*_ does not accept **kwargs.

Comment: Where is `Timer` defined?

Comment: Timer is imported from Python threading module.

Comment: `threading.Timer` wants a single parameter that is a dict of keyword parameters for the function to invoke, NOT individual keyword parameters.

Comment: You also seem to have misunderstood how `**kwargs` work. It creates a dictionary where you can get values from just as an ordinary dict (`kwargs['dir']`). As of now, the variables `dir` and `fmt` in `__init__` doesn't exist anywhere

Comment: And you haven't created an instance from the class yet, but am still trying to use an instance method. Create a instance first with `instance = messageachiver(dir='something', fmt='something')`

Comment: Also, try to use [PEP8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Use `snake_case` for variables, functions, methods, and modules, `PascalCase` for classes and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for constants.

Comment: @ jasonharper: thanks. that is true.

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman: thanks. now the problem is the method gets called only once - when the time is up. It's supposed to be called every interval time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific init error is because you are passing multiple variables to the timer class.

In this line:
`Timer(86400, messageachiver.archive, dir = message_archive_dir, fmt = message_archive_format)`
You are passing the archive function, the dir variable, and the fmt variable to TIMER and not to the messageachiver class. Timer has no named variables for dir and fmt.

So the line should be `Timer(86400, messageachiver.archive)`

This only partially fixes your problem though. Because you are never actually initializing the class with the variables you need them to have. So *before* you call timer, you need to initialize the class messageachiver by adding `mymessageachiver = messageachiver(dir = message_archive_dir, fmt = message_archive_format)`

Also you need to put your class definition *before* you try to initialize it.
The final code:

```
from threading import Timer

class messageachiver(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.message_archive_dir = kwargs['dir']
            self.message_archive_format = kwargs['fmt']

    def archive(self):
            print("message_archive_dir is " + self.message_archive_dir)
            print("message_archive_format is " + self.message_archive_format)
            print("Archiving trade messages")


message_archive_dir = "achivedir"
message_archive_format = "zip"
mymessageachiver = messageachiver(dir = message_archive_dir, fmt = message_archive_format)
# That's a huge wait time, try something like 10 for a smaller wait during testing.
archive_timer = Timer(86400, mymessageachiver.archive) 
archive_timer.start()
```

Comment: The error is no more. I ran your code by setting the interval to 5, inserting if \__name__ == '\__main__':  after the class and a infinite loop at the end, the timer went off only once. Do you have any idea why the timer does not repeat every 5 seconds?

Comment: @techie11 I would have to see your "infinite loop" to be able to tell you that. Timer isn't a class to make something happen every X seconds. Timer will make something happen *once* after X seconds has passed. Check out the [Timer docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)