# kwargs multiple argument in function definition gives an error in function call

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-multithreading, keyword-argument

I am using class for threading multiple parameters passing. It gives me an error of

> File "c:\dev\scripts\scratch.py", line 33, in 
> thread_lnk_date_applied = ParseThreading("//th[contains(text(),'Application Validated')]/following-sibling::td", value_date=True)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\dev\scripts\scratch.py", line 7, in **init**
> self.value_link = kwargs['value_link']
> ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> KeyError: 'value_link'

class definition is below

```
class ParseThreading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,var_xpath,**kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.value_link = kwargs['value_link']
        self.value_date = kwargs['value_date']
        self.value_status = kwargs['value_status']
        self.var_xp = var_xpath

def run(self):
    if self.value_date:
        try:
            var_date = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,self.var_xp))).text
            self.value_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(var_date,'%a %d %b %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        except TimeoutException:
            self.value_date = '-'
    if self.value_status:
        try:
            var_status = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,self.var_xp))).text
            self.value_status = var_status
        except TimeoutException:
            self.value_status = '-'
    if self.value_link:
        try:
            var_link = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,self.var_xp)))
            self.value_link = var_link.get_attribute('href')
        except TimeoutException:
            self.value_link = '-'
```

I call it in the lines of,

```
thread_lnk_date_applied = ParseThreading("//th[contains(text(),'Application Validated')]/following-sibling::td", value_date=True)
thread_lnk_date_decision = ParseThreading("//th[contains(text(),'Decision Issued Date')]/following-sibling::td",value_date=True)
thread_status_decision = ParseThreading("//th[contains(text(),'Decision')]/following-sibling::td",value_status=True)
thread_doc_link = ParseThreading("//p[@class='associateddocument']/a",value_link=True)
```

My code was different before, I assigned class variables to `False`, my aim is only var_xpath variable will be string all other class variables will be used just one of them with value True.
But, looking after [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472025/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-dir)  I re-assigned class variables to kwargs[].
But error remains same.
Can someone help with Why issue of this error?

Comment: `__int__` is not how you spell that.

Comment: yes, that was also wrong. but code does not seem work anyways giving keyerror now

Comment: Every one of your call lines only provides 1 kwarg, so trying to get the rest of them will give a key error